# Can i safely use RJ11 and 24 guage wiring for hobby leds?

Tags: led, wiring, telephone

I would like to supply power to a bunch of LEDs (a dozen or so) on a model train layout.  I would like each light to be modular, so I could easily unplug  a building and replace it, etc.  The LEDs are low voltage.  I haven't built a driver yet but anticipate using a current mirror.  The wires to each light would be at a few volts, 3-ish, and carry a current of maybe 15 to 20 mA.

I am on a very tight budget and would like to improvise with what is on hand.  It just so happens that my house is full of 24 guage wires in phone cables with 4 conductors from many abandoned RJ11 phone jacks.

Is there any reason that it wouldn't work to use these wires and jacks to connect the lights?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes

There will be absolutely no problems. In fact, those wires are even overkill for the purpose - designed for around 48 volts and enough current to ring the mechanical bell in an old telephone.

The only reason you might not want to use them is because they are *too thick*, but that's only a mechanical issue in your case.